# Erro ao criar filters global com vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Estou tentando criar alguns filtros globalmente no vuejs mas estou recebendo o erro "Failed to resolve filter".

Meu main.js está assim

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';

Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.filter("teste", function(value){
        return "OK";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Faltou provavelmente você importar o filter desejado. O que aconselho fazer em caso de um filter global:

1. Crie um arquivo js separado, em uma pasta filters por exemplo. Cada arquivo será um filter, exemplo abaixo de um filter simples:

**name-substr-format.js**

```
export function nameSubstrFormat (name, number = 33) {
  if (name) {
    return name.substring(0, number)
  }

  return ''
}
```

O filter acima é um arquivo que exporta apenas uma função, no caso sua funcionalidade é limitar a quantidade de caracteres de uma string. Se não passar nada, retorna 33 caracteres no máximo.

2. Agora importe-o em seu `main.js` e chame-o em sua instância Vue:

`import { nameSubstrFormat } from './filters/name-substr-format'`
`Vue.filter('nameSubstrFormat', nameSubstrFormat)`

3. Para utilizá-lo direto em seu HTML, basta chamá-lo dentro de uma interpolação, após o *pipe* ("|"), sendo que o primeiro parâmetro se torna a variável da interpolação.

`<span>{{ nome | nameSubstrFormat(20) }}</span>`

Note que ele pode ser utilizado tanto com variáveis dentro de seu `data()`, quanto variáveis computadas (*computed properties*).

Answer (score 0):

Seu script parece está certo parece que o problema é no componente, tente assim:

```
Vue.filter('teste', function(value) {
   if (value) {
      return 'ok'
   }
})

<template>
   <div>
     {{ var | teste }}
   </div>
</template>
```